Public imports of svg not working in Next JS v14.2.1 which was previously working in v14.0.3
I have updated all the packages of my NEXTJS project using
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install

I haven't changed any other files after updating it.
Now when I am running the project and the page is trying to access the SVG import form the public directory, it gives the following error
Module not found: Can't resolve 'public/images/svgs/cart-icon.svg'

The resource is present there and the name is also correct.
This is the import statement
import CartIcon from 'public/images/svgs/cart-icon.svg';

I have tried debugging it but as it is working in the previous version, I guess I might be missing some dependencies or any other configuration. If anyone has an idea on how to fix this, please reply.

should have been import CartIcon from '/public/images/svgs/cart-icon.svg';

What do you mean? It worked for me with the /public.

If your svg is placed in the directory public/my-img.svg, then there are 2 ways of using the SVG in a Nextjs 14 project -

import Image from "next/image";
import MySvgImg from "/public/my-img.svg";


    <Image
      width={50}
      height={50}
      alt="My Image Svg"

      src={MySvgImg} // Method 1

      // OR

      src="/my-img.svg" // Method 2
    />



